# Как реализовать запуск скрипта по логике?

Tags: linux, cron, скрипт, логика

Есть скрипт, который проверяет папку на наличие новых файлов,  tar'ит эти файлы и отправляет архив на sftp.

Нужно, чтобы этот скрипт запускался каждый день в 2 часа, если скрипт зафейлился, то нужно, чтобы он запускался снова в 4 часа, если опять зафейлился, то в 6. В 6-ть последний запуск, если снова зафейлил,ся то отправить письмо с результатами и больше ничего не делать.

Думал это как-то через cron решить, но не получается.

Подскажите кто что думает по этому поводу , как это сделать ?

Подскажите как это можно сделать. Как сделать, чтобы скрипт в случае фейла запускался в другое время, а в случае удачного выполнения отправлял письмо и останавливался? Накиньте шаблончик если не сложно

Comment: пишите bash скрипт со всей логикой и его cron'ом запускаете в 2 часа каждый день

Answer (score 1):

три раза запускаете скрипт, третий раз с произвольным доп. параметром.

алгоритм работы скрипта:

1. если флаговый файл существует и обновлён сегодня, то завершить работу
2. если копирование завершилось успешно, то обновить флаговый файл (`touch флаговый.файл`) и завершить работу
3. иначе, если передан доп. параметр, отправить письмо

Comment: `man at` — не верю, что вы первый раз про это слышите.